# How to properly structure code in CakePHP 3 using MVC structure and communicate between controllers?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp-3.0

How do I properly structure my code in CakePHP 3 using MVC structure when I am adding multiple entries to different database tables that involves different controller methods?

I am fairly new to coding in general, but am determined to figure out the proper way to structure my code.

I am building a website with CakePHP 3 and I have a checkout page that has the ability to add 1 or 2 users depending on the membership level as well as process a payment.

The checkout method is in a my MembershipLevelsController. This controller is used for CRUD operations for the different levels of membership. Users navigate to the list of memberships (index method), select the level they want and it sends them to a checkout (view) page for that level.

So, this checkout view has a possibility of three forms.
1.) User #1 (posts to users/add method)
2.) User #2 (posts to users/add method)
3.) Custom Stripe Form. (posts to membershipLevels/charge method)

The charge method is saving returned stripe response data to the membership_orders table.

Currently I am using ajax and sending the user data. Now normally the add method has its own template(view) to add users, but I have it set up to add 1 or 2 users and process a payment in a different view.

I am unsure if this is the proper way to structure my code? It seems logical that the users controller would do all of the processing of user information i.e.(any CRUD operations). Or, should I do all of the processing in a different controller i.e. the MembershipLevels Controller, or the MembershipOrders Controller?

One argument is that when I am sending user data from membership_levels/checkout view to the users/add controller method, the validation errors are sent to the users/add view. Since I am currently using ajax I was able to inject the response with validation errors meant for the users/add view into my checkout view, but I am unsure if this is the right way to do it?

I have also ran into a dead end. I need to also be able to connect the first (or Primary) user account created with the order that is being created (i.e. saving the id for the new user into the user_id field in my membership_orders table), but this seems impossible the more I try. Which brings me to my second argument for processing all the information in a different controller method.

Argument two: when the first user is added I would need a way to communicate that id number with the controller that I am working in, but I can't figure out how to do that. It seems I can create a variable after the user info is saved that contains the id number, but only afterwards because the id isn't known until after I have saved it right? (since it is auto-incremented)

It seems like CakePHP might automatically add the user_id if I processed everything in the Orders Controller (because the orders table and the users table are linked by user_id), but I want my code to be DRY and do not want to re-use code to add a user in a different controller.

MembershipLevels Controller:

```
private function stripeConfig() {
    $stripe = [
        "secret_key"        => "sk_test",
        "publishable_key"   => "pk_test"
    ];
    $set_key = \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
    return [$stripe, $set_key];
}
public function charge() {
    $this->stripeConfig();
    $token = $this->request->data('stripeToken');
    $amount = $this->request->data('billing_amount');
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email' => $this->request->data('email'),
      'card'  => $token
    ));

    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => $amount*100,
      'currency' => 'usd'
    ));

    $orderTable = TableRegistry::get('MembershipOrders');
    $order = $orderTable->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $order = $orderTable->patchEntity($order, $this->request->data);            
        $order->user_id = $this->request->data('user_id'); //Can't even save a hard coded number with a hidden input for this field.
        $order->billing_name = $charge->card->name;
        $order->billing_street = $charge->card->address_line1 . " " . $charge->card->address_line2;
        $order->billing_city = $charge->card->address_city;
        $order->billing_state = $charge->card->address_state;
        $order->billing_zip = $charge->card->address_zip;
        $order->billing_country = $charge->card->address_country;
        $order->subtotal = $charge->amount/100;
        $order->tax = 0;
        $order->total = $charge->amount/100;
        $order->payment_type = $charge->card->funding;
        $order->card_type = $charge->card->brand;
        $order->account_number = "XXXX XXXX XXXX ".$charge->card->last4;
        $order->expiration_month = $charge->card->exp_month;
        $order->expiration_year = $charge->card->exp_year;
        $order->status = $charge->status;
        $order->gateway = "Stripe";
        if ($customer->livemode === true) {
            $order->gateway_environment = 'live';
        } else {
            $order->gateway_environment = 'sandbox';
        }
        $order->subscription_transaction_id = $customer->id;
        $order->payment_transaction_id = $charge->id;
        $order->timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        if ($orderTable->save($order)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The order has been saved.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The order could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }

    $this->set(compact('token', 'customer', 'charge'));
}
public function checkout($id = null) {
    $keys = $this->stripeConfig();
    $membershipLevel = $this->MembershipLevels->get($id, [
        'contain' => []
    ]);
    $userTable = TableRegistry::get('users');
    $user = $userTable->newEntity();
    $this->set(compact('keys', 'user', 'membershipLevel'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['membershipLevel', 'user']);
}
```

Users/Add Controller Method:

```
public function add()
{
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        if(!empty($this->request->data('role'))) {
            $user->role = $this->request->data('role');
        } else {
            $user->role = 4;
        }
        if( $this->request->data('second_user_added') === '1' ) {
            $user->second_user_added = $this->request->data('second_user_added');
        } else {
            $user->second_user_added = 0;
            $user->code = $this->uniqueToken();
        }
        if( !empty($this->request->data('primary_user')) ) {
            $user->group_id = $this->request->data('username');
        } elseif ( !empty($this->request->data('secondary_user')) ) {
            $user->group_id = $this->request->data('secondary_user');
        }
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $user_id = $user->id;
            $this->Flash->success(__('You have been added.'));
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'home']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('You could not be added. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

MembershipOrdersTable:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('membership_orders');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Sessions', [
        'foreignKey' => 'session_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Memberships', [
        'foreignKey' => 'membership_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}
```

UsersTable:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);
    $this->table('users');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
    $this->hasMany('MembershipOrders', [
       'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am unsure if this is the proper way to do it, but I figured out 2 different ways to add the users Id to the Orders table.

1.) I save the stripe token when adding the primary user and then when saving the data for the order I add the user Id where the stripe tokens match.

i.e.:

```
if ($order_id = $ordersTable->save($order)) {
    $usersTable = TableRegistry::get('Users');
    $query = $usersTable
        ->find('all')
        ->where(['affiliate_token' => $order_id->affiliate_token])
        ->first();
    $order_id->user_id = $query->id;
    $ordersTable->save($order_id);
    $this->Flash->success(__('The order has been saved.'));
}
```

2.) I log the primary user in when they get added and then I can just grab the user id that is logged in and save that to the order when I add the order.

i.e.
App Controller:

```
public function beforeRender(Event $event) {
    $this->set('logged_in', $this->Auth->user('id'));
}
```

Users/Add method:

```
if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
    if( !empty($this->request->data('primary_user')) ) {
        //Make sure no on is logged in already
        if( isset($logged_in) ) {
            $this->Auth->logout();
        } else {
            //Log user in using Auth if primary user
            $this->Auth->setUser($user->toArray());
        }
    }
    $this->Flash->success(__('You have been added.'));
}
```

MembershipLevels/Charge method:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $order = $ordersTable->patchEntity($order, $this->request->data);
    if ( isset($logged_in) ) {
        $order->user_id = $logged_in;
    }
    $order->membership_level_id = $this->request->data('membership_level_id');

    etc...
}
```